# Find the absolute minimum and maximum values of $f(\theta) = \cos \theta$

Tags: calculus

**The Problem**

Find the absolute minimum and maximum values of the following function on the given interval:  $\ f(\theta) = \cos \theta; -\pi \leq \theta \leq {\pi \over 6} $

**What I've Done So Far**

1. Find the derivative of $\ f(\theta) $.  This equals $\ -\sin \theta $.
2. Determine critical points.  It won't ever be undefined, but I know there are points within the interior of the domain where the function is equal to zero.

So where I'm stuck is finding at what points $\ f(\theta) $ equals zero.  Is it as simple as taking the inverse $\ \sin $ of $\ \theta $?

Thanks!  Any help will be much appreciated!

Garren

Comment: You could just check it from the graph of the cosine function

Comment: True.  But I would like to learn from the problem so that I can also find the answer algebraically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a function $f$ then at the maxima and minima of $f$, we have $f'=0$.
$$f(\theta)=\cos(x)\implies f'(\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$$
We know that:
$$-\sin(\theta)=0\implies \sin(\theta)=0\implies \theta=\pi k,k\in\Bbb{Z}$$
Since we have a domain $-\pi\leq\theta\leq\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, we have maxima or minima at $0\pi=0$ and $-1\pi=-\pi$. And:
$$\cos(0)=1$$
$$\cos(-\pi)=-1$$
So we have a maximum at $(0,1)$ and a minimum at $(-\pi,-1)$. Since there are no other multiples of $\pi$ in the interval $-\pi\leq\theta\leq\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and therefore no other solutions to $-\sin(\theta)=\theta$ in the interval, we are done.